# Using horizontal scroll view with table view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

So I am working with a designer to create the to-do app below, and I have got everything except displaying the data on each page.

https://projects.invisionapp.com/share/4BMYIMOYP9W#/screens

My question is, how should I create a horizontal scroll view that can have multiple table view inside of them? I have tried using xib, which is the method from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq71SPkJIus&), but I can't put tableviews in the view. I have also tried to use PageController, but with that I can't detect which way the user scrolls, which is part of how I change the date that the user is on. Today I tried using ViewControllers with a scrollview, but I can't edit any of the labels on the ViewController. I will put the code I currently have below.

`ViewController.swift`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var date: Date!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let firstPage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstPageViewController")
    let secondPage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondPageViewController")
    let thirdPage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdPageViewController")
    let viewControllers = [firstPage,secondPage,thirdPage]

    var idx:Int = 0
    for viewController in viewControllers {

        addChildViewController(viewController);
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(viewControllers.count), height: scrollView.frame.height)
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(idx), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height);
        scrollView!.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        idx += 1;
    }
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = view.frame.width
    self.scrollView.delegate = self


    if defaults.object(forKey: "date") == nil {
        date = Date()
    }else {
        date = defaults.object(forKey: "date") as! Date
    }


    let decoded  = defaults.object(forKey: "data") as! Data
    let decodedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [ToDo]
    defaults.set(date, forKey: "date")

    let dateFormatterDate = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterDate.dateFormat = "LLLL dd"
    let dateFormatterDay = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterDay.dateFormat = "EEEE"


    //self.dayLabel.text = (dateFormatterDay.string(from: date))
    //slide1.day.text = (dateFormatterDay.string(from: date))

}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let dateFormatterDate = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterDate.dateFormat = "LLLL dd"
    let dateFormatterDay = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterDay.dateFormat = "EEEE"

    var x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    if x >= view.frame.width * 2 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = view.frame.width
        x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        date = date.days(value: 1)
    }else if x <= 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = view.frame.width
        x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        date = date.days(value: -1)
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
extension Date {

    func days(value: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: value, to: noon)!
    }


    var noon: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
}
```

I just honestly have no idea how to crack this one, I am about to ask the designer to redesign the UX, but I really like how it works now. Or at least, how it is supposed to work. Sorry if this is a newbie question, I am very new to swift.

Comment: I used https://github.com/uias/Tabman, There is also a manual way I could show you, but this is easier te implement. I've used this in a solution with three VC's wherein the middle one was a dynamic tableview.

Comment: as per your requirement did u looked at using collection view(as u said u want to put multiple table view inside horizontal scroll view).